# Fluid Extbase HTML not correct

Tags: format, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have this Code:

```
<f:format.html>{article.text}</f:format.html>
```

My Problem is that if i have a Tag like object oder param in the {article.text.} The Code doesn't compile this an show me the normal text.

Is there a other possibility to prevent this ?

Thanks

Comment: What does gives you a <f:debug>{article.text}</f:debug>? Are the HTML tags stored in your database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "show me the normal text", but the problem could be that the `format.html` view helper uses `lib.parseFunc_RTE` by default: http://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/CoreProjects/MVC/fluid.git/blob/HEAD:/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/HtmlViewHelper.php#l86

So you could try to allow the tags with

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(object, param)
```